# Пробел между переменными при выводе информации

Tags: html, php

Есть строка, как вставить между переменными пробел?

```
 <p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО: <?php echo $name_teacher, $surname_teacher,              $last_name_teacher;  ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае не важно, но с точки зрения экономии памяти оптимальнее:

```
<p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО: <?php echo $name_teacher, ' ', $surname_teacher, ' ', $last_name_teacher; ?></p>
```

Так как при конкатенации строк оператор "`.`" и при join/implode создается временная переменная в которую копируются все входящие строки, и при достаточно длинных строках (в примере это `$name_teacher`, `$surname_teacher` и `$last_name_teacher`) возможна нехватка памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
echo $name_teacher.' '.$surname_teacher.' '.$last_name_teacher;
```

Можно так:

```
echo join(' ', array( $name_teacher, $surname_teacher, $last_name_teacher ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Неразрывный пробел - `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "{$name_teacher}, {$surname_teacher}, {$last_name_teacher}";  ?>
```

если не ошибаюсь